# Regex for angular dimension visualisation

Tags: .net, regex

I want to implement a validator for a control where angular values can be edited.

The format is `DDD°MM'SS,xxx`.

The values I want to accept are in the interval `[0°00'00'' - 359°59'59'']`.

The second part should be edited as floating number.

Comment: Will there always be a decimal part, or is the `,xxx` part optional?

Comment: That part is optional

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to do it in a single regex:

```
^(3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])°[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9](,[0-9]+)?''$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^              # Start of string
(              # Start of group:
 3[0-5][0-9]   # Match either a number between 300 and 359
|              # or
 [12][0-9]{2}  # a number between 100 and 299
|              # or
 [1-9]?[0-9]   # a number between 0 and 99 (no trailing zeroes allowed!)
)              # End of group
°              # Match °
[0-5][0-9]     # Match a number between 00 and 59 (trailing zero required!)
'              # Match '
[0-5][0-9]     # Match a number between 00 and 59 (trailing zero required!)
(,[0-9]+)?     # Match optional decimal part
''             # Match ''
$              # End of string
```

Comment: @Ωmega: Not really. GPS accuracy alone is more than 10 times higher than can be expressed with integer arcseconds (1 arcsecond corresponds to around 30 m). If you want coordinate precision in the cm range, you need at least three decimal places.

Comment: I am talking about order in your pattern. It looks okay for me to have `148°49'22,134''`, but weird to have it in your format `148°49'22'',134`.

Answer (score 1):

If no leading zeros are allowed for `DDD` part and optional decimal part of `SS` is 1-3 digits long with comma being a decimal separator, then you should use regex pattern

```
^([1-2]\d|3[0-5]|[1-9])?\d\xB0([0-5])?\d\x27([0-5])?\d(?:,\d{1,3})?(\x27{2}|\x22)?$
```

---

If leading zeros are allowed for `DDD` part, then go with pattern

```
^([0-2]\d|3[0-5]|\d)?\d\xB0([0-5])?\d\x27([0-5])?\d(?:,\d{1,3})?(\x27{2}|\x22)?$
```

---

Additionally, if leading zeros are mandatory for `MM` and `SS` parts, then use pattern

```
^([0-2]\d|3[0-5]|\d)?\d\xB0([0-5])\d\x27([0-5])\d(?:,\d{1,3})?(\x27{2}|\x22)?$
```

---

All above patterns allow digits in `SS` part to be followed with `''` or `"` sign, as well as with no sign at all.

Comment: Shouldn't the first group be optional?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in .NET, as per your tags, I wouldn't do the whole thing in Regex. I'd retreive the pertinent parts through regex, convert them to integers, and validate that they are within the range as a secondary step.

That would leave you with something like `(\d{1,3})°(\d{2})'(\d{2})''` for your regex, and I'm sure you can figure the rest of the .NET code yourself.